# only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts - W2CWM2C wavelets

Tags: r, time-series, wavelet

I am using the W2CWM2C package as part of my project in the investigation of wavelets applied to time series data.

I use the W2CWM2C package to perform bivariate wavelet correlation on my data and then plot them to the screen.

Similar to the W2CWM2C documentation on [pg 6](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/W2CWM2C/W2CWM2C.pdf) I am using 2 time series variables

```
> class(wideRawTS)
[1] "mts"    "ts"     "matrix"

> head(wideRawTS[,c(1:2)],10)
Time Series:
Start = c(1, 1) 
End = c(1, 10) 
Frequency = 96 
         DO0182U09A3 DO0182U09B3
1.000000     -101.50     -103.37
1.010417     -101.32     -102.75
1.020833     -101.45     -103.30
1.031250     -100.91      -95.92
1.041667     -100.91     -103.04
1.052083     -100.97     -103.67
1.062500     -101.48     -103.26
1.072917     -100.85     -103.86
1.083333     -100.87     -103.96
1.093750     -100.77     -103.33
```

For those interested, my original data was stored in a dataframe and represented 2 weeks of network data recorded in 15 min intervals. The data has a 24hr seasonality i.e peaks occur roughly every 24 hrs and since there are 1:1343 measurements per variable therefore the frequency is 4 x 24 = 96, I do hope this is right!

I have used the following code for a sample of my data

```
wideRawTS <- ts(wideRawDF[,2:13], frequency = 96)
U09A3_B3 <- wideRawTS[,c(1,2)]
Wname <- "la8"
J <- 8
lmax <- 10
compWCC <- WCC(U09A3_B3, Wname, J, lmax, device = "screen", NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
```

When I run this code i get the following error:

```
colnames DO0182U09A3 DO0182U09B3
Error in zz[1:(n.length - 1)] : 
  only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
```

Would this have something to do with my data being negative? I've googled the error and I came across this post but was over my head. From reading some of the comments I believe the issue was related to positive and negative subsetting and I am not sure if it's applicable here.

If anyone has any experience with a similar type of problem I would be delighted to hear about how you resolved it.

To provide a reproducible example [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxgkBr1CkDf7cHVaQXViajhLVE0/view?usp=sharing) is a copy of the wideRawDF dataframe hosted on google drive.

Comment: What is the datatype of  `n.length`?

Comment: @Kevin, excuse my ignorance but how can I check this? I assume that the code is trying to find the length of the two variables in my matrix which are of type time series which is what is required for the WCC function. Have I missed something here?

Comment: I am not sure where the `n.length` comes from. If it is variable you made then typing `str(n.length)` in the console will describe it. I often find that I am using the wrong datatype (i.e. dataframe instead of list, etc) and the function can't successfully cast it to the required type.   If `n.length` is ZERO then you are mixing positive and negative subscripts and that could be the reason for the error.

Comment: @Kevin, I just tried but "object n.length not found". I have also double checked my code and I have no variables by that name. Regarding the class of the input data x, as per the first print out above I am passing a matrix of time series to the WCC function which is whats required. I am really stumped, I have tried to take the problem back to basics and carefully imported and checked the structure/class/dim of the data and I think I've ticked all the boxes in that regard. Thanks for your help anyway, I really appreciate it.